# Creating .dll from a Python file

Tags: python, dll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [py2exe to generate dlls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550446/py2exe-to-generate-dlls)

I'm searching for a way to make a .dll-file out of a python file. I also wonder if I can use the functions in the dll from an another language like C++ oder Assembler?
I have been looking at py2exe and pyapp, but it doesn't provide porting to dll.

I'm sorry for this question. I feel sorry because I didn't search StackOverflow before for similar questions / possible duplicates .

Comment: consider that any scripting language which is "compiled" must necessarily embed pretty much the entire interpreter inside that executable, especially if the script does any kind of `eval()` type stuff. it's even harder to componentize such a thing into a .dll

Answer (score 5):

You can compile multiple python scripts into an assembly using clr.

```
import clr
clr.CompileModules("modules.dll", "module.py", "module2.py")
```

This is IronPython, but to reference these modules from other languages (ex. C++ or C#) IronPython would be preferable in my opinion because it runs as a .NET interpreter that can be understood by other languages that implement .NET

To reference the compiled dll from another IronPython script, for example:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("modules.dll")
```

Comment: How can one define a DllMain in this approach?