# Using Elmer to generate C code and then create dll

Tags: python, dll

I wanted to see if anyone has tried something like this and to get some advice whether or not to pursue this idea.  I have a Python script which I would like to create a dll from.  After doing some research, the best way to perform this task would be to embed the python script into C and then generate a dll from the C code.

I then found Elmer Software Glue:  http://elmer.sourceforge.net/index.html, which embeds a Python module into C.  I am thinking I could use Elmer to embed my python code into C and from there create a dll.

I anyone would give me some reassurance that this could work and if not maybe some alternatives.  I am open to any and all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I contact the individuals behind ELmer and they were nice enough to create an example as to how to create a DLL from the code generate from Elmer.  The example can be found in the following link:  http://elmer.sourceforge.net/examples.html#WINDOWSDLL

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how things worked out for you, but I was able to create a DLL using Elmer with Python 2.7.8 and Elmer 1.1.7a on Windows 7 x64 and figured I'd share my experience.

My compilation/build environment was VisualStudio2005 using NMAKE

I did run into several issues along the way, especially related to the -frozen flag and my older version of visual studio, but I am getting what appears to be a working DLL now.

My top level notes:

- I had to statically link elmer with MSVCRT80 due to a conflict during dll loading with the MSVCRT90 included by python27.dll.
- The library, elmer.lib, was needed for the linking step, but existed only in the c:\elmer\src\build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\elmer directory, it seems like it should get copied someplace without the word temp in the name, but I set my makefile to use it from the temp directory.
- When using -frozen, there can be dozens of generated .c files
- PyImport_FrozenModules and Py_FrozenFlag are already declared by other include files (pydebug).
- PyImport_FrozenModules is getting redefined (due to elPythonToC), rather than just assigned.
- DL_IMPORT (used within elPythonToC.py) is deprecated per http://bugs.python.org/issue566100. should use PyApi_DATA instead I think, but makes no real difference.**EDIT** Not that important as I deleted that entire block as it was redefining PyImport_FrozenModules
- In the end, I had to include python27.dll, elmer.dll. I believe MSVCRT90.dll also needs to be installed via the MS redistributable installer on the target machine as python27.dll needs that.  It would be nice if using frozen would get us a single distributable, but I'll take what I can get.
- I was able to run the procedure on python 2.6.5 with slight modifications (e.g. python path is c:\python26 instead of c:\python27).
- Test your script in python first, elmer will happily package a script containing malformed python.
- To create a debugable dll, add `/Z7 /Od` to the CFLAGS and `/incremental:no /debug` to the LINKFLAGS
- Would be nice if some sort of formatted comment or function in the python code itself could replace the .elm file.

Now here are the detailed steps of I did (no warranties that any of these are correct and they were certainly not optimal, but they did seem to work for me):

- Install Elmer

  - Download and unzip elmer to some directory (I picked C:\elmer, so I'll use that throughout my example)
  - When I started, I was using 2.7.2 and I ran into this issue: [Compiling with cython and mingw produces gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno-cygwin'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034390/compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc-error-unrecognized-command-line-o/6035864#6035864).  I patched Lib/distutils/cygwinccompiler.py to remove -mno-cygwin and got it to install, but I later installed 2.7.8, which I think fixes the underlying issue.
  - I wanted the Elmer.dll to statically link to the MSVCRT junk as I have an older version of MSVCRT, so I modified setup.py as follows.  (I know I shouldn't statically link and you probably don't want that, but in case you do:
  - Add `extraCompileArgs = []` and `extraLinkArgs = []` below the `libDirs = []` declaration
  - In the Windows-specific build options if block add: `extraCompileArgs = ['/MT']` and `extraLinkArgs = ['/MANIFEST']`
  - Add `, extra_compile_args=extraCompileArgs, extra_link_args=extraLinkArgs` after `libraries=libs` inside `Setup(..., ext_modules=[Extension(`
  - from command prompt, run C:\elmer\src>python setup.py build
  - from command prompt, run C:\elmer\src>python setup.py install
- Modify .py and .elm files to suit my needs - that was the easy part
- Obtain makefrozen.py makefrozen is used by elmer when using the -frozen option, but it does not appear to be included in the standard win32 MSI distribution.

  - makefrozen is included in the source code for python, but is not included in the windows MSI installer, so download the source tarball from www.python.org
  - extract \Tools\freeze\ to c:\python27\Tools\freeze
- Modify buildAndRun

  - Change ELMERDIR to C:\
  - Path should point to `SET PATH=%PATH%;%ELMERDIR%;%THISDIR%`
  - Set ELMERDIR to C:\elmer\
- Update Make files to work for my configuration (the example files didn't work at all with nmake or frozen). Here is my MAKEFILE that can build the frozen or non-frozen version using nmake:

  ```
      PYTHONDIR=C:\Python27
      ELMERDIR=C:\elmer
      ELMERLIBDIR=$(ELMERDIR)\src\build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\elmer
      ELMER_OUTPUT_DIR=Generated

      CC=cl
      RM=del /F /Q
      ELMER=$(ELMERDIR)\elmer
      shell=call

      CFLAGS=/TC /LD
      INCLUDEFLAGS=/I$(ELMER_OUTPUT_DIR) /I$(PYTHONDIR)\include /I$(PYTHONDIR)\Lib\site-packages\elmer
      LINKFLAGS=/LIBPATH:$(PYTHONDIR)\libs python27.lib /LIBPATH:$(ELMERLIBDIR) elmer.lib

      .PHONY: generatedFiles generatedFrozen all allFrozen
      SRCS = Generated\*.c
      OBS = $(SRCS:.c=.obj)

      {Generated}.c{Generated}.obj::
          @echo Compiling...
          @$(CC) /nologo $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDEFLAGS) /c /FoGenerated\ $<

      generatedFrozen:
          echo Elmering
          @$(shell) $(ELMER) -c -frozen -o $(ELMER_OUTPUT_DIR) -int MyDll.elm MyDll.py

      generatedFiles:
          echo Elmering
          @$(shell) $(ELMER) -c -o $(ELMER_OUTPUT_DIR) -int MyDll.elm MyDll.py

      showIncludeAndLinkFlags:
          @echo includeDirs: 
          @$(shell) $(ELMER) --printIncludeFlags
          @echo linkDirs: 
          @$(shell) $(ELMER) --printLinkFlags

      MyDll.dll: $(OBS)
          @echo Linking...
          @Link $(LINKFLAGS) /DLL $(OBS)

      all:
          @echo "Making All"
          @nmake  generatedFiles
          @nmake  showIncludeAndLinkFlags
          @nmake  MyDll.dll

      allFrozen:
          @echo "Making All"
          @nmake  generatedFrozen
          @nmake  showIncludeAndLinkFlags
          @nmake  MyDll.dll

      clean:
          @echo cleaning
          $(RM) .\Generated\*.* 2>nul || echo eatFailure >nul
  ```
- Create a Build.bat to setup the Visual Studio environment before calling nmake.  Here are the contents of my build batch file:

  ```
      @ECHO OFF
      SETLOCAL
      SET THISDIR=%~dp0
      REM Setup Visual Studio build environment
      REM  Microsoft Visual Studio 8 == Visual Studio 2005
      CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\vcvarsall.bat"
      nmake clean
      nmake allFrozen
      pause
      ENDLOCAL
  ```
- Fix compilation/link errors, it got a bit ugly here as I had to modify elmer code to get it to work

  - Remove duplicate declarations and redefinition for Py_FrozenFlag and PyImport_FrozenModules

    - Open C:\python27\Lib\site-packages\elmer\elPythonToC.py in a text or python editor
    - Delete or comment out the `if( frozenFlag ) :` block containing `retCode += "extern int Py_FrozenFlag;\n"` and `retCode += "DL_IMPORT(struct _frozen *) PyImport_FrozenModules;\n"` (around line 145)
    - Add the line: `retCode += "      PyImport_FrozenModules = _PyImport_FrozenModules;\n"` above the line containing `retCode += "      retRunVal = PyImport_ImportFrozenModule( (char*)\"%s\" );\n"` (around line 189)
- Copy DLLs to a distribution folder

  - Copy MyDLL.dll from the working directory containing your .elm file. Copy elmer.dll from C:\elmer\src\build\lib.win32-2.6\elmer. Copy python27.dll from C:\Windows\SysWOW64.
  - Install Visual C++ Redistributable Package if necessary on target machine (or maybe just find MSVCRT90.dll in your windows side-by-side configurations and stuff that next to your DLL.  see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235299.aspx.

---

**EDIT**
When I added some meat to my dll, I noticed the frozen import stuff wasn't working properly and was causing my DLL to exit.  My original modifications were causing Py_FrozenFlag and PyImport_FrozenModules to be defined locally, which caused PyImport_ImportFrozenModule to fail within the generated c code.  I've made modifications to the makefile to eliminate the Py_NO_ENABLE_SHARED define, removed the definitions and declarations of those vars, changed the definition of PyImport_FrozenModules to an assignment and everything seems to be working properly now.  I've successfully connected to and debugged my dll from a simple c++ app.

Comment: could you please update the working version? I have tested mingw64 and Visual Studio 2019, but all of them said there are many errors in elCpp.cpp, so that I can't get elmer.lib. Thanks