# how can i turn python code into windows dll

Tags: python, py2exe

With py2exe, I can turn python code into an execute program for windows. 
Now I want to turn my code into a window DLL, so that other programs can call my function.
How Can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550446/py2exe-to-generate-dlls

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your .py to .dll by using shedskin.

http://code.google.com/p/shedskin/

I believe the command to make it a dll is

```
shedskin -e
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a .dll ≈ .pyd by adapting your code to [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/tutorial.html)